# error on starting grafana service

Tags: mysql, grafana

I have grafana 4.4.3 on an ubuntu 16.4 LTS which is installed on an vm and its IP is 1.2.3.4 . 
I also have a mysql database version 5.0.95 on a CentOS 5.9 and its ip is 5.5.5.5 and mydatabase name is : voip

I want to set mysql as backend for grafana. I'v changed my grafana.ini file like this:

```
###[database]###    
type = mysql
host = 5.5.5.5:3306
name = voip
user = root
password = t@123
###[session]###
provider: mysql
provider_config = `root:t@123@tcp(5.5.5.5:3306)/voip`
```

I also set my root account to be used as a remote account.

when I want to start grafana-server service, it gives me this error:

```
Fail to initialize orm engine" logger=sqlstore error="Sqlstore::Migration 
failed err: this user requires old password authentication. If you still 
want to use it, please add 'allowOldPasswords=1' to your DSN. See also 
https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/wiki/old_passwords\n"
```

what should I do? Did I don anything wrong?

Comment: The error message actually tells you what you need to do... Although, you may want to upgrade your mysql to a newer version (there is no such mysql version as 14.12, you got that wrong)

Comment: I'm realy sorry. the database version is 5.0.95. and one more thing.... allowOldpassword is set in my my.cnf file.

Answer (score 0):

`allowOldPasswords` error is given when you are using old version of mysql database. to change this you should go to `/etc/my.cnf` and change `oldpasswords = 1` to `oldpasswords = 0`. next you have to login to your mysql and then enter these commands:

```
 SET SESSION old_passwords=FALSE;
 SET PASSWORD FOR 'user_name'@'%'=PASSWORD('<put password here>');
 flush privileges;
```

and at last, restart your mysql service.

hope this post is helpful...